# find the first or last commit a patch applies to

Tags: git, patch, git-patch, git-bisect, git-apply

Assuming a patch was created from a specific commit in the past, and no longer applies to HEAD.

How can I find either the first or better the last commit in the history of HEAD, where this patch applies with "git apply" ?
Maybe something with git bisect? But which command will tell me if a patch applies?

Ideally I want to move back to that commit, apply the patch, then rebase on or merge with the original HEAD, and diff again to create a new patch, unless there was a conflict.
After this I would like to go back to the original HEAD, so I can continue with more patches.

Background: There is a number of patches that need to be rerolled...
(and yes, there are ecosystems where patches are still a thing..)

Comment: Where the patches created with `git diff`, or `git format-patch`?

Comment: if the git bisect is going to be too difficult, maybe I could use the patch file created timestamp to find the commit to start with.. but ideally i want to know how it works with bisect :)

Comment: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366539/how-to-apply-a-very-old-patch-in-git Now we only need to wrap that further so it can be automated to reroll 100 patches.

Comment: Well darn, I was just about to finish working on a Bash script too `:P`

Comment: go ahead! the link is nice, but it could have some more handholding for people who use git bisect for the first time :)

Comment: So wait, there's a problem, `git bisect` requires that you pass it one "good revision", which in this case is a revision where the patch applies without conflicts. `git bisect` won't always be a good tool for this because of that, I suspect.

Comment: I'm exhausted, I'm calling it a night. The answer you found was way better than any Bash script I would have made anyways.

Comment: ah crap. and now that i think about it, it does make sense.

Comment: so maybe better a loop to search backwards. This can be expensive. But, maybe out of a 100 commit history, there are only 5 commits where the patch applies, e.g. commits 50 - 54. The only way to find these would be backwards search from commit 100.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help.
Maybe i am going to do try something which uses the commit file timestamp. If I get something useful I will post it.

Comment: And btw, here is where I am coming from: https://drupal.org/node/2247991#comment-8819487 I have not seen xjm's script yet, but wanted to see how I would do it.

Comment: You know you can also use `git log -S <search-string>` or `git log -G <regex>` to find the first addition/deletion of a line `<search-string>` or `<regex>` too, right? It might help you find possible candidates for "the first commit" where a patch might have been generated from.

Comment: yes, but i'd say this is more a heuristic than something reliable enough for automation..

Comment: Are you one of the core maintainers? If you are, have you considered using `git format-patch` to generate patches? The patches themselves will record which commit they come from.

Comment: I am an occasional contributor, but not a maintainer. And I like format-patch, but some reviewers don't..

Comment: Okay, well I'm off to bed. Maybe someone else will come along and have a better idea. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that the patches were created with `git diff`, and not `git format-patch`, and that your default pager for your `git log` is `less`.

Here is an example of a patch created from `git diff <sha1> <sha2>`,

```
diff --git a/osx/.bash_profile b/osx/.bash_profile
index c7b41df..fb80367 100644
--- a/osx/.bash_profile
+++ b/osx/.bash_profile
@@ -3,6 +3,10 @@
 # Setup PATH for Homebrew packages
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

+# Setup Scala variables
+export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Frameworks/scala # Symlinked directory
+export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
+
 # Initialize rbenv,
 # https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x
 eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Take this line:

```
+export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Frameworks/scala # Symlinked directory
```

and search for it in `git log --patch` or `git log -p`. Type `/` when in `less`, then enter the regex you want to search for:

```
/\+export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Frameworks/scala # Symlinked directory
```

The `+` is escaped with `\` here, because it's a special character in regexes. Hit enter to find the first match, and `n` to bring up the next match, or `N` to go to the previous match.

This will help you find commits that might be possible candidates for where the patch came from. You can also use spacebar in `less` to page down, and `b` to page up.

Comment: Hm. this can be useful, but it is far from automatically finding the correct commit, so i could bulk reroll patches..

Comment: Also I wonder why a line from the patch should be anywhere in the log? E.g. if the patch adds "vanilla ice", but the history of HEAD has no such a thing?

Comment: @donquixote working on a better solution with `git bisect`, give me about 10-15 minutes. Also, have you seen what `git log -p` does? It adds diff information to the logs.

Comment: git apply --check looks promising

Comment: so, git apply --check prints stuff ("error ...") if it fails, but prints nothing if the patch applies cleanly. Now this needs to be combined with git bisect..

Comment: yes, `git log -p` is fun, and i did not know it before. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### The way git wants you to do this

`git apply --3way` should locate the base versions of each file using blob hashes and merge forward all in one step, assuming they exist somewhere in your repo history and you can deal with the merge conflicts.  That's possibly an easier solution for many people.

### The way to do what you asked for

If you still really want to know a historical commit that contains the base files a diff came from, my script below expands one of the solutions to [locate commits containing a single blob hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob) to try and find commits containing a group of blob hashes pulled from a patch file.

```
#!/bin/sh
# git-find-patch-base takes a patch produced by "git diff" and tries to locate commit(s)
# containing all source blobs

# The first parameter is the name of the patch file to examine
patch_file="$1"
# Any remaining parameters are passed as a group to the git log command using $@ below
shift

# Make a temporary file and capture a list of all the starting
# file blob hashes that the patch used in it. Note: Adding a file shows
# a starting hash of 00000000, so we filter that one out...
tmp_blob_file=$(mktemp)
echo "Examining patch file \"$patch_file\"..." 1>&2
grep -E "^index" "$patch_file" | colrm 1 6 | colrm 10 | sort | uniq | grep -v 00000000 > "$tmp_blob_file"

# Count how many unique blob hashes we identified
blobcount=$(cat "$tmp_blob_file" | wc -l)
echo "Found $blobcount unique blob hashes in patch..." 1>&2

# Use git log to get a list of commits to check against. Then, for
# each of those commits, count how many of the blob hashes that we
# wanted appear in it, and output the commit hash if it's at least the
# ideal blob count. Note: this is an imperfect searching method, since
# there is a chance for hash collision, exacerbated since the grep is not
# forcing the short hashes to only match the beginning of the long
# hashes.
echo "Searching log/tree history of git..." 1>&2
git log "$@" --pretty=format:'%T %h %s' \
| while read tree commit subject ; do
    if test $(git ls-tree -r "$tree" | grep -f "$tmp_blob_file" | wc -l) -ge "$blobcount" ; then
        echo "$commit" "$subject"
        break
    fi
done

# Clean up the temporary file we made...
rm "$tmp_blob_file"
```

The first parameter is the name of the patch file to analyze, and any remaining parameters are passed to `git log` to help expand/restrict the list of commits to check against.  If you want the first commit relative to a specific branch, you can run `git-find-patch-base foo.patch branchname`.  If you're completely lost as to where something is from, you can run `git-find-patch-base foo.patch --all` and go get some coffee while it does it's thing.  There are a lot of useful limiters on git log like `--grep` or `--author` that can speed up this process.

The script as shown stops on the first match with the `break` out of the while loop.  You can remove that and it will exhaustively search all the way back spitting out all candidate commits.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the imperfections of the search method could be eliminated by doing `git apply --check` against the commit, but that would also require a `git checkout` in the script to do so...